# Is the Session State stored on the client side or the Serverside?

Tags: oracle-apex

Is the Session State stored on the client side or the Server side? 
I am new to apex and I am starting to understand that when a field is change that value only exists on the client side, but when I use a dynamic action to 'set value' in the session state is that session local to the client or does the session exist on the server?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Session State is a server-side thing. It stores values of items for server-side calculations (processes, queries, validations, links, etc.).

But at the same time each item has a value on the client-side too. This value is stored in the page. When you use a Dynamic Action with type `Set Value`, it sets a value on the client-side. There are three ways to send it to the server (in APEX 5.x):

- submit the page
- execute another Dynamic Action with type `Execute PL/SQL code`, and in the properties of this DA you need to put the name of the item into the property `Page item to submit`. If you don't need to actually execute any PL/SQL code and just need to send the value, put `null;` as PL/SQL code
- create an `AJAX callback` and write a JavaScript code to send values. See more details in the [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/database/apex-5.1/AEAPI/apex-server-namespace.htm#GUID-45B43DB1-9601-4BD6-9B7C-6C41C35BEE49) of `apex.server.process` function.